# Finding an approximate double-zero using binary search

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, binary-search, mathematical-analysis, real-numbers

Let $f$ be a continuous real function on $[-1,1]$. The function is accessible via *queries*: for any $x$, the value of $f(x)$ can be computed in constant time.
If $f(-1)<0$ and $f(1)>0$, then by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ has a *zero* --- an $x \in [-1,1]$ for which $f(x)=0$. Suppose we want to find a zero approximately, that is: given $\delta>0$, find an interval of length at most $\delta$, that contains a zero. This can be done using binary search: start with the entire interval $[-1,1]$; let $c$ be the middle of the interval; if $f(c)=0$ we are done; if $f(c)>0$ then recursively search between the leftmost end of the current interval and $c$; if $f(c)<0$ then recursively search between $c$ and the rightmost end. After $O(\log(1/\delta))$ steps, the interval length is at most $\delta$. So the run-time is polynomial in the length of the binary representation of $\delta$.

Now, suppose we have *two* continuous functions, $f$ and $g$, both defined on $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. Suppose $f(-1,y)<0$ for all $y$ and $f(1,y)>0$ for all $y$, and $g(x,-1)<0$ for all $x$ and $g(x,1)>0$ for all $x$. By the [Poincare-Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem), there exists a *double-zero*, that is, a point $(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ such that $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$. We want to find a double-zero approximately, that is: given $\delta>0$, find a square of side-length at most $\delta$, that contains a double-zero. Is it possible to do in time $O(poly(\log(1/\delta))$?

I tried to apply binary search, but it did not work. If I could know, for example, that for some $c\in[-1,1]$, $f(c,y)<0$ for all $y$, then I could recursively search the rectangle $[c,1]\times[-1,1]$. But there is no reason to think that such a $c$ exists.

**Can this problems be solved using $O(poly(\log(1/\delta))$ queries?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0885064X89900174) studies a similar problem: finding an approximate fixed-point of a two-dimensional function from the unit square to itself, which is accessible via value queries. The authors prove that computing a fixed point with $p$ decimal digits requires $\Omega(2^p)$ queries. Equivalently, computing a square of side-length at most $\delta$ that contains a fixed point requires $\Omega(1/\delta)$ queries.

---

I claim that the same is true for finding a double-zero with *general* functions. The proof is by reduction from the fixed-point problem. Let $h$ be a continuous function for which we want to find a fixed point, and suppose it is a function on the square $[-1,1]^2$. Define two functions $f$ and $g$ as follows:

$$ 
f(x,y) := x - h(x,y)_1
\\
g(x,y) := y-h(x,y)_2
$$

Note that $$
f(-1,y) \leq (-1) - (-1) = 0 ~~~~ f(1,y) \geq 1 - 1 = 0
\\
g(x,-1) \leq (-1) - (-1) = 0 ~~~~ g(x,1) \geq 1 - 1 = 0,
$$
so the pair $(f,g)$ has a double-zero. Moreover, $(x,y)$ is a double-zero of $(f,g)$ if and only if it is a fixed point of $h$. Therefore, finding an approximate double-zero requires $\Omega(1/\delta)$ queries.

---

For the case of *monotone* functions, I [asked a separate question in cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52739/9453).

Comment: @YvesDaoust ??? An $\Omega(1/\delta)$ bound implies that an $O(\mathrm{poly}(\log(1/\delta)))$ bound does not hold, directly answering the question in the negative.

Comment: Right, sorry, my bad.